# difference between get_sidebar() & get_template_part()

Tags: wordpress

what is the difference between get_sidebar() & get_template_part() in wordpress.Can second one replace first one without making any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_template_part() is like a  "include" file.whatever template file you  need that template file must located in your theme you can call.

```
Ex:

  get_template_part('templatename').
```

If you have multiple sidebar.each sidebar have diffrent type widget that time using this one.

get_sidebar() is  a calling widget in your file.

```
Ex: get_sideabr('main');

     get_sidebar('left');
```

Answer (score 2):

get_template_part() Load a template part (other than header, sidebar, footer) into a template. Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code and an easy way for child themes to replace sections of their parent theme.

Comment: If you do not want header, sidebar, footer then you can use get_template_part()

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer please dont forget to upvote my answer. thanks